# Display sticky div on scroll-up?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 2 bars - **Primary** and **Secondary Nav Bar** as shown in below image.
When Scrolled Down the secondary bar becomes sticky and the primary hides.

[Code Link](https://codepen.io/sharathm89/pen/BaNWgYz)

[image]

When I scroll up, I need primary to re-appear: primary and secondary should be **sticky** until they reach the top.

```
.top-container {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.header {
  padding: 10px 16px;
  background: #555;
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

.content {
  padding: 16px;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.sticky + .content {
  padding-top: 102px;
}
```

**JS Code**

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var header = document.getElementById("myHeader");
var sticky = header.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > sticky) {
    header.classList.add("sticky");
  } else {
    header.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```

Comment: So what have you tried for this. Please show us some code

Comment: @MaheerAli https://codepen.io/sharathm89/pen/BaNWgYz

Comment: From a deleted answer: https://jsfiddle.net/harshsetia/r56eyzdm/3/

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 thanks let me check it

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 the secondary header hides when its scrolled top..